# Gravar arquivo em banco de dados com NHibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate

É possivel serializar e gravar arquivo em banco de dados com NHibernate?

```
public virtual File Arquivo { get; set; }
```

Ele não deixa mapear e não queria gravar sem usar o NHibernate para seguir o padrão

Comment: É possível. Como você faz o mapeamento das classes?

Comment: Dê uma olhada neste post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26686392/2588695

Comment: Se for semelhante ao EntityFramework, você deve mapear uma propriedade byte[] para o campo no banco de dados que representa este arquivo (varbinary por exemplo).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sim, é possível. No C# o tipo terá que ser **`byte[]`** e não **`File`**.

Até porque `File` é uma classe estática, você nunca vai conseguir usar uma instância de `File`.

No mapeamento ficaria:

```
Property(x => x.Arquivo, map =>
{
    map.Type(NHibernateUtil.BinaryBlob);
    map.Length(Int32.MaxValue);
});
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, usei da seguinte forma:


    `public virtual byte[] Arquivo { get; set; }`


    `byte[] FileSream = File.ReadAllBytes(txtArquivo.Text);
    Objeto.Arquivo = FileSream;`


aparentemente gravou normalmente, agora estou pesquisando como faz para retornar essa informação e gravar o arquivo em um diretório.

Comment: Pelo que você está dizendo, parece ser o caso de [marcar uma resposta como aceita](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/). Aqui não escrevemos "resolvido" na questão. Se tem uma resposta que realmente te ajudou, marque-a como aceita. Se chegou sozinho à solução, poste a solução como resposta. Assim o conteúdo fica mais organizado e fácil de ser encontrado futuramente por outras pessoas com problemas parecidos.